# CSS floated list and bottom margin between sections

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create a floated list of items, and these are broken up into 2 sections.

The problem is, the margin I am applying to give some space between to 2 divs is not working correctly, due to the floated items I think.

https://jsfiddle.net/hc7muswj/

I want some space between the first list and the next H2.

How do I make the first div have "solidity" to allow me to margin bottom from it?

```css
.lozzy {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.lozzy h2 {
  clear: both;
}

.lozzy ul {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.lozzy ul li {
  width: fit-content;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  background-color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Toolkit</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://pageaffairs.com/notebook/containing-floats/

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements will by default not be wrapped by their containers. (If you add a border or background to `.lozzy` you'll see what I mean.)

Add `overflow: auto;` to the container element (`.lozzy`)  to make it wrap (i.e. contain) the floated items (and thereby have the `margin-bottom` you defined)

```css
.lozzy {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  overflow: auto;
}

.lozzy h2 {
  clear: both;
}

.lozzy ul {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.lozzy ul li {
  width: fit-content;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  background-color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Toolkit</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

By the way: Having `float: left` *and*  `display: inline-block;` on the same element is superfluous. You can solve your problem also by simply deleting the `float: left` since `display: inline-block;` will bring you a very similar result. In this case you won't need the `overflow` setting on the container which I used in the snippet above:

```css
.lozzy {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.lozzy h2 {
  clear: both;
}

.lozzy ul {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.lozzy ul li {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  background-color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Toolkit</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, I'll take a look through and try to digest it!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of `float`. `float` is not supposed to be used for styling purpose. It is a mis-used hack. Use flexbox-instead. Float is for floating images within a text paragraph. Your intended layout can be achieved the evry same with the actual right tool of `Flexbox`.

For that add: `.lozzy ul { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }`.

Also dont use so many `!important;`. They are nearly always (with exeptions of overwriting templates etc.) an indication that something is done wrong. That an issue is rather hidden the resolving the issue. For example like you hide the list-bullets with !important. You could simply use `list-style: none;`

```css
.lozzy {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.lozzy ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  list-style: none;
}

.lozzy ul li {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  background-color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="lozzy">
  <h2>Toolkit</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>First thing</li>
    <li>Second thing</li>
    <li>Third thing</li>
    <li>Fourth thing</li>
    <li>Fifth thing</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! You left float on the li, is that intentional?

Comment: oh no it was not intentionally. fixed it!